# Can't select an option

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

I have this html code

```
<select id="stuff" name="stuff_name">
<option value="10002">Team_01</option>
<option value="10001">Team_02</option>
<option value="10000">Team_03</option>
<option value="0">[default]</option></select>
```

I'm trying to select "Team_02" by using css_selector in selenium with python.
Why this works: `element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option:nth-child(2)')`
And this doesn't : `element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option[value="Team_02"').click()`
The point is that i want to select with 2nd method, because the value constanly changes.

## Important:

Can't use value, because it always changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try if want to use xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='stuff']/option[contains(text(),'Team_02')").click()
```

or you can try like brute-force.

```
for option1 in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@id='stuff']/option"):
    if option1.text == 'Team_02':
        option1.click()
        time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Still `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='stuff']/option[contains(text(),'Team_02')"].click()` does not work? could share more details what u think not sensitive?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work. The point is that i selected from previous dropdowns like this element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option[value="Team_02"').click(), but for this particular dropdown it doesn't work and i don't know why.

Comment: At that code line, it says that it can't find the element by that path.

Comment: Are there more than one `Team_02` in the page  if not then `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='stuff']/option[contains(text(),'Team_02')").click()` should work. Is there more than one?

Comment: Not with the same name, no. I know it should because method 2 that i wrote in the main post when using css_selector works for other dropdown.

Comment: maybe there is a way to insert vaue into this expression: element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option:nth-child(2)') use child and instead of "2" use value ? Is it possible ?

Comment: i'll try that brute-force of yours at work tomorrow :)

Answer (score 3):

From your question I understand you want to use CSS (since you can also use Xpath or the Select-class of Selenium)

Using CSS you can either search via the value-attribute, but then you need to ask for the value-number

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option[value="10001"]').click()
```

or you search via the text:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option[text="Team_02"]').click()
```

another way would be the innertext

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option[innertext="Team_02"]').click()
```

Comment: Can't use value, because it always changes and with text it's now working also, sry.

Comment: maybe there is a way to insert vaue into this expression: element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#stuff > option:nth-child(2)') use child and instead of "2" use value ? Is it possible ?

Comment: You are missing the closing ] in your CSS selectors... all three of them. I would edit it but it's not enough characters... :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`selenium.webdriver.support.ui.Select`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html) as below.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("stuff"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Team_02")
```

Comment: I tried this before posting this question, didn't work also. Also triend to .send_keys("\n") by simulating Enter press, that didn't work too.